# How to include existing VBA code from XLAM in c# VSTO add in

Tags: c#, vba, excel, vsto

I've got an xlam with VBA code in it that exposes functionality via a ribbon group called 'Group 1' and a separate c# VSTO for Excel that exposes functionality via a ribbon group called 'Group 2'.

I'd like to move some of the functionality out of the VBA file and into the C#.

a) Can I 'include' the VBA in the C# easily somehow so I don't have to go and migrate it all to c#?
b) Can I create the ribbon group items/buttons in the C# add in but have the code reference back to the .xlam file?

I've seen this link ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465290(VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465290%28VS.100%29.aspx)) which seems to talk about publishing multiple solutions which I don't think is what I'm after  - although would this method work for deploying the .xlam from within the VSTO app (and at least simplify deployment of the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I 'include' the VBA in the C# easily somehow so I don't have to go and migrate it all to c#?

The simple answer is no, you can't.

You would need to re-write the *logic* in C# (*or VB.NET if your "Group2" add-in is already based on VB.NET*) in an VSTO add-in (*assuming it's an application add-in*). Don't get scared though, it should rather be fun and easy + you will learn the basics of C# while doing it. If you are quite good with VBA then it's an advantage for you because you would most likely already understand the Excel Object Model.

- see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/cc668205.aspx for details
- and [VSTO and C#](http://blog.concentra.co.uk/2013/05/20/excel-add-in-using-vsto-and-vba/)
- and then [vba4all.wordpress.com](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/c-and-vba/) for some extra tips & real-life examples

> Can I create the ribbon group items/buttons in the C# add in but have the code reference back to the .xlam file?

No. You may want to look up [**Custom UI Editor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc508991%28office.11%29.aspx#UsingtheCustomUIEditor2_AddingTemplatestotheCustomUIEditor) if you plan to add or modify a ribbon exclusively of C#.

What you can do then is design your Custom Ribbon in Visual Studio and then copy and paste the XML to the Custom UI Editor to achieve pretty much the same look. The advantage you get with Visual Studio is intelli-sense!

For a good walk-through on Custom UI Editor and creating a ribbon see [Ron De Bruin's wesite](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section2.htm)

Comment: The second link VSTO & C# is perfect thank you! See section of the article called 'Call VBA Macros using C#'; we already have the workbook with macros loaded when Excel opens so I should be able to reference it using that methodology.

Comment: (in the short term anyway; longer term I'll migrate it back into the VSTO natively)